# Removing \n from list being split into variables - Python

Tags: python, list, replace

So here's the code I'm working with:

```
# This is initialization for Twitter OAUTH
with open(curdir + '\OAUTH.txt', 'r') as f:
    words = f.readlines()
    data = [w.replace('\n', '') for w in words]

CONSUMER_KEY = data[0]
CONSUMER_SECRET = data[1]
ACCESS_KEY = data[2]
ACCESS_SECRET = data[3]
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

f.close()
```

So basically, I'm trying to read each line and deposit them into the API variables without any extra stuff like '\n'. The file OAUTH.txt looks like this:

```
45623sdajHJGSQqwdewf
hrjkewrrew892391hnfbndsjhkfb278f93
hb3278dndlwwoerrewewr
r3h278cewwooweoifnccvbdgdhsshdgs
```

How can I use the keys alone as input for vars like CONSUMER_KEY, etc. without other chars like '\n'?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should use `os.path.join`, by the way. `with open(os.path.join(curdir, 'OAUTH.txt'))`
`f.close` is also outside of the context manager

Comment: This should work, what's the problem?

Comment: this is the value:

data[0]
Out[40]: 'sXsFJjeHhDYFykFfn6sKbDVSe\n'

And it is what is being passed to CONSUMER_KEY

Comment: it's not cross platform

Comment: thanks @corvid for os.path.join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: adding the reason why yours probably isn't working.

> Environment.NewLine resolves to \r\n on Windows and \n on Unix like systems.

Given the backslash in your path, it appears you're using windows, meaning that `\n` is not the correct newline character.

#### Solution 1:

[os.linesep](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.linesep)

#### Solution 2:

One option that's probably a bit easier is to create a file with some sort of delimiter. For example:

```
CONSUMER_KEY=45623sdajHJGSQqwdewf
CONSUMER_SECRET=hrjkewrrew892391hnfbndsjhkfb278f93
ACCESS_KEY=hb3278dndlwwoerrewewr
ACCESS_SECRET=r3h278cewwooweoifnccvbdgdhsshdgs
```

Then you can split on the delimiter and construct a dictionary.

```
with open(os.path.join(curdir, 'OAUTH.txt')) as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  # line regex, to test that the line can be split correctly.
  line_regex = re.compile('^\w*[=]{1}\w*$')
  api = { line.split('=')[0]: line.split('=')[1] for line in lines if line_regex.match(line) }
```

Then you have a single data structure related to the data.

Comment: Thank you. I need a break. I had it looking precisely as you have it but actually overthought it and made it just the keys; exacerbating the goal.

Comment: btw, you should really export the oauth keys as environment variables

Comment: Mind elaborating a little? It has occurred to me to do it a billion ways at this point.

Comment: If you're using a linux-based machine, you can use `export VARIABLE_NAME="some_value"` from the command line. Then in python, you can fetch that variable using `os.environ.get('VARIABLE_NAME')`

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I do not get a neat variable without '\n' in it. I also haven't figured out if the single quotes will need to be removed as well or not. Worrying about \n for now.

Comment: @corvid Oh yes. I may end up doing that when I deploy this to a cloud setup but as I work in WIndows I'll stick to my ugly approach.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi What version of python are you running, environment? Canopy, Win8.1, 2.7 for me.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Oh wtf it just started working was this all for nothing how is that possible I did absolutely nothing different. I didn't even close the project.

Comment: @DylanMoore I doubted this all from the start. Your code looked great from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

corvid's way is probably great, but I'm lazy. When it comes to settings files like this, I tend to prefer

settings.py (or, usually, sekrit.py, since I have that on a global .gitignore)

```
CONSUMER_KEY="SEKRIT1"
CONSUMER_SECRET="SEKRIT2"
ACCESS_KEY="SEKRIT3"
ACCESS_SECRET="SEKRIT4"
```

And then when I need my secrets....

```
import sekrit

sekrit.CONSUMER_KEY
```

Why bother messing around with reading files when you can just get python to do it for you?

Comment: This is interesting. Thanks and I'm going to think about implementing.

Comment: Or for something in between, use json or yaml, for which there are tools in the standard library.